# PostgreSQL SELECT-RULES , inheritance, row-level permissions

Tags: postgresql, rules, postgresql-9.2, row-level-security

Here's what I've been reading:

```
 http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/rules-views.html
 http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/rules-privileges.html
```

**My goal is to allow a login to see only those *rows* that it "owns", so to speak.**

Let's say every table in the database inherits from this table:

```
   create table WHOAMI
   ( 
      tenant varchar(25) not null default current_user
   );
```

for example:

```
   create table FOO
   (
     id int primary key,
     invoicedate date
   ) inherits (WHOAMI);

    insert into FOO(id, invoicedate) values(1,now()::date);

    select * from FOO;

    --abclogin|1|2013-02-01
```

Is there such a thing in PostgreSQL as a schema-level select rule, *affecting all tables and views in the schema*, that appends to every select, insert, update, or delete statement a condition that says, in effect, `..AND WHERE TENANT = current_user`?  If there isn't such a global rule, can it be done on a table-by-table basis?  I am not having any success with my attempts, and am probably misunderstanding a few things about how rules are created. Here is what I have tried to do:

I try to create a select-rule:

```
  CREATE RULE "_RETURN" AS ON SELECT TO FOO DO INSTEAD
  SELECT * FROM FOO where tenant = current_user;
```

but get this error: `ERROR:  could not convert table "foo" to a view because it has indexes`

I try to create a view with a *security-barrier*:

```
       CREATE VIEW TENANTFOO WITH (security_barrier) AS
       SELECT * FROM FOO WHERE tenant=current_user;
```

and then attempt an insert:

```
        insert into TENANTFOO(id,invoicedate)
        values(2,(now()::date);
```

but get this error:

```
        `ERROR:  cannot insert into view "tenantfoo"
         HINT:  You need an unconditional ON INSERT DO INSTEAD rule
         or an INSTEAD OF INSERT trigger.`
```

What steps are required to implement row-level security barriers on tables?

Answer (score 2):

In your last example, you'd need to run the `INSERT` **against the table** or create another RULE: `ON INSERT TO TENANTFOO DO INSTEAD`.

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is a [Row-Level Security](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/RLS), it is not yet available, although [some work had been done on this thing](http://www.postgresql.org/message-id/CADyhKSWGtZqpsXtF7_q2FvKRvX6RqW+xv7VmxNmj4gubSBoo-g@mail.gmail.com). I hope this patch will make it into the upcoming 9.3 release.

Meanwhile, I've been working with the following design a while ago.

Requirements were similar, views should have been delivering only those rows intended for the `CURRENT_USER`. In our case access had been done quite simple: a table that specified whether given user had access for the given relation and given key, smth like:

```sql
CREATE TABLE user_grants (
    user_id     integer,
    entity_name text, -- should exist in pg_class
    entity_id   integer
);
```

Then, say for the `tasks`, the following view had been created:

```sql
CREATE VIEW tasks_v AS
SELECT t.*
  FROM tasks t
  JOIN user_grants ug ON t.user_id = ug.user_id
   AND ug.entity_name='TASKS' AND ug.entity_id = t.task_id;
```

Of course, the setup is not complete without a number of helper functions, triggers and rules. Also it was necessary to make sure some reasonable default privileges are always granted.